# Disable location indicator on network access permanently on LineageOS/Android 12

Tags: lineageos, notification-bar, developer-options, location-services

The status bar location indicator on Android 12 also gets shown for network and connectivity access.

[image: location indicator]

This results in it being visible every few seconds on my phone. For me, that defeats the purpose of a location indicator, as it becomes normal to see it popping up every so often.

I've found that the developer options contain an option to disable that exact behavior.

[image]

The problem is that this option keeps resetting itself all the time. I would like to keep this disabled or find a way to periodically disable the option, e.g. by Tasker.

Does anyone have an idea to keep this disabled?

If it helps somehow, my phone runs LineageOS, is rooted, has Xposed installed, and I have a license for Tasker. If there is some way to change the developer setting via a script, I am open to it.

Comment: Is this something related to LineageOS or specific device models? **Edit:** looks like it is [a combination of both](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/un728j/is_this_a_bug_or_a_new_feature/). Meanwhile, I found an Xposed module called [Location Indicator Whitelist](https://modules.lsposed.org/module/fr.netstat.locationindicatorwhitelist), which might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `adb shell` (or Tasker/... with root) to disable the location indicator:

```
cmd device_config put privacy location_indicators_enabled false default
```

It won't be gone completely, but displayed as normal icon like the Wi-Fi or cellular indicator.

If you also want to disable the camera and microphone indicator use:

```
cmd device_config put privacy camera_mic_icons_enabled false default
```

It's not persistent though and needs to be applied in once in a while (I set it to once an hour)