# Disable location icon in status bar for single app

Tags: lineageos, notification-icons, android-12

I'm using /e/OS 15 (Android 12, a privacy-focused fork of LineageOS) on my Fairphone 4.

After upgrading to Android 12, one of the changes I noticed is that every couple of seconds, the location icon appears in the status bar and stays there for a moment as a blue dot.

I know that is related to exactly one app that regularly checks for my location and Android wants to inform me about this.

Although I consider this useful in most cases, for this app it is pretty annoying.

Is there any way to disable the notification **only for this app** in the status bar? I already discovered the setting to **completely** hide the location notification, but that's not what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may get a more focused audience by posting in the comminity forum of /e/ os: https://community.e.foundation/

Comment: Isn't it a pure Android feature?

Comment: AFAIR there are status bar icons for camera and microphone access in plain Android, but not for location.

Comment: That's a valuable information, thx! So I'll try it in the /e/OS forum

Comment: Here the related question: https://community.e.foundation/t/disable-location-icon-in-status-bar-for-single-app/45377

Comment: Workaround can be found here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248964/disable-location-indicator-on-network-access-permanently-on-lineageos-android-12